# Change Style of Scrollbar in DropDownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, coding-style

Can anyone tell me how can I change the default style of DropDownlist scrollbar

I use below style property to change scrollbar style but its not working for dropdownlist

```
.scrollbarstyle
{
    scrollbar-face-color: #BAC8D5;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #DCF5F8;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #DEE3E7;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #879BA9;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #E0EAEF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #90ABBE;
}
```

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Never use these styles for a drop down list***. It will work only in IE.

Instead use some div and use script and style to make and appear as a combobox.

Check [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html) for a Yahoo solution

For a jQuery based one, check [this](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Comment: thnaks, 
that fine but i want that with asp.net dropdownlist contol because i want selected index change event for that.

Comment: You won't be able to do it in a cross browser way in a dropdownlist control. But you can achieve this using a div and can code using javascript for selected index changed.